# Ways for retrieving GET variables to a php page

Tags: get

What's the best way to retrieve the GET (in URL) variables passed to a .php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your url is `exmaple.com/file.php?var=value` then 'value' is stored in `$_GET['var']`

Comment: Sure is :) you can select my answer if you like :D

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your GET-request is of the form `page.php?var=1` :

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['var'])) {
        echo $_GET['xyz'];
    }
?>
```

If you are using a PHP framework however, it may supply you with alternative ways.